# Стилизация checkbox в JSP

Tags: html, css, jsp

Есть страничка с стилизированым средствами CSS3 checkbox.
В таком коде работает нормально:

```
<div id="checkbox">
    <input type = "checkbox" name = "agree" id="flag_choice" required>
    <label for="flag_choice" class="agree_checkbox_label"></label>
</div>
```

А вот в таком варианте с тегом JSP (сами теги работают исправно) значок галочки уже не отображается:

```
<div id="checkbox">
    <form:checkbox id="flag_choice" path="agreementDTO"/>
    <label for="flag_choice" class="agree_checkbox_label"></label>
</div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема.

Вот сам CSS:

```
#checkbox {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#flag_choice {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: none;
}

.agree_checkbox_label {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.agree_checkbox_label:before {
    content: "";
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px 
rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: absolute;
}

#flag_choice:checked + .agree_checkbox_label:before {
    content: "\2713";
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    font-size: 15px;
    color: green;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

JSP генерирует вот такой HTML (не понятно почему 2 инпута):

```
<div id="checkbox">
    <input id="flag_choice" name="agreementDTO" required="true" 
      type="checkbox" value="true">
    <input type="hidden" name="_agreementDTO" value="on">
    <label for="flag_choice" class="agree_checkbox_label"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: посмотрите, какой в результате получается html. скорей всего когда jsp преобразовывается в html меняются какие-то атрибуты (id, class) у input. и лучше меньше использовать id, а все делать на class.

Comment: Указал какой генерируется HTML. Что интересно, если вручную в готовой странице убрать этот скрытый второй инпут, все работает как нужно. Но изначальный вопрос остается открытым

Comment: вы знаете, что значит `+` в селекторе?

Comment: При выполнении первого условия, в данном случае :checked, выполнятся изменение стилей моего label, что собственно и рисует нужную мне галочку в стилизованном checkbox. Дело в том, что при установлении клике на стилизованный лейбл, скрытый чекбокс-инпут активируется/деактивируется. Просто галочка в лейбле не появляется

Comment: Я так и не понял, вы знаете или нет?

Comment: Похоже я понял где ошибка, вечером попробую исправить. Спасибо что напомнили про селекторы.

Comment: я в CSS просто не силён. Так что как исправить не знаю, но подозреваю, что дело в +

Answer (score 0):

Решение вопроса следующее:

```
#flag_choice:checked + .agree_checkbox_label:before
```

(тут выбор следующего элемента).

заменен на:

```
#flag_choice:checked ~ .agree_checkbox_label:before
```

(тут выбор всех элементов такого типа среди дочерних элементов #checkbox)

спасибо **Mikhail Vaysman**